# .bat will not stop running via Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, batch-file, clickonce

All,

I have a .bat file that runs a command line command.

**The contents of the .bat:**

```
start C:\Tasks\MemberInterestFollowUp.application
```

I tested it by running it from the Task Scheduler window. It executes but does not exit; I have to explicitly end the program from the Task Scheduler. I thought that by having "start" at the beginning of the command that the program would exit automatically but it's not

I even added the keyword "exit" after the 1st command but that did nothing noticeable as far as exiting goes:

```
start C:\Tasks\MemberInterestFollowUp.application
exit
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: ok, just updated my question with the exact code in the .bat file

Comment: ok question what type of application is MemberIntersectFollowup.application` have you looked up how to use `TASKKILL` command

Comment: Your app could have put up a message and is waiting for a response.  Are you able to see the console window?  If yes, add an echo statement after the START line to prove that you are getting beyond it.  If no, append something like this to the START line and then look for a potential message or error message in the log file.  >> Log1.txt 2>> Log2.txt

Comment: i looked at this (great suggestions) the app is running to completion and not throwing up any dialogs that would prevent a timely exit

Comment: `schtasks /create /?` mentions a parameter `/z` to delete the task, when finished. Is it that, what you are looking for?

Comment: OK, you may want to try appending >nul 2>nul instead of the logging I suggested, because if there is ANY output there may be no place for it to go.  Are you sure you even need a bat file for this?  Can't you just start your app with the scheduler?

Comment: when I got it right, the problem is not with a not-exiting program, but with a not-disappearing entry in TaskScheduler.

Comment: I have lost track of whether there is a problem any more. ???